# Арифметическое сжатие

Tags: алгоритм

Если кто знаком с методом арифметического сжатия, подскажите - как выкрутиться из ситуации. При раскодировке нормально декодируются только <=13 символов. Остальные - не те, т.к. не попадают в свои интервалы.   Что делать?

Comment: проблема с вашим кодом? предъявите его.

Comment: Проблема не с кодом. А с алгоритмом - т.к. идет деление больших дробных чисел, в результате чего они не влазят в свои интервалы.

Comment: С такой информацией вам сможет помочь только телепат =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Без кода конечно сложно сказать, но смысл же предельно простой.*

Есть некоторый **вещественный тип данных**, кодирующий ваше самое сообщение. Понятно, что точность в этом самом вещественном типе напрямую зависит от количества бит, которые тратятся на мантиссу числа. И есть некоторый теоретический предел точности, после которого операции с вещественными числами с плавающей точкой просто перестают быть точными.

Идея правильного арифметического кодирования текста **произвольной длины** заключается в том, чтобы "впихнуть" максимально возможное количество символов в вещественный тип и **сигнализировать** о том, что в это количество бит больше не влезет ни одного символа без возможной потери точности.

*Очевидно, что существует некоторый теоретический предел количества этих самых символов, который опирается на спецификацию `IEEE754` и базовые принципы анализа погрешностей.* Способ вычисления этого предела приводится в некоторых статьях, например в референсах на вики.

---

**Теперь чуть ближе к практике.**

Нужно каким-либо образом определить точную верхнюю границу числа символов, которые можно закодировать, например, с помощью *32 битного типа с плавающей точкой.* Сделать это можно, просто "прикинув" это число или попытаться установить точную границу, опираясь на теорию метода.

Здесь не могу сказать точно, *(не хватает знаний и желания читать соответствующие статьи)* будет ли зависеть эта оценка от применяемого алфавита кодирования или нет, предполагаю, что можно найти некоторый **инвариант**, который подойдет для любой кодирующей таблицы.

Ну а дальше все просто - мы знаем, что, допустим в 32 бита у нас влезают максимум `N` символов для того, чтобы расшифровка выполнялась однозначно. Эти самые символы кодируются в 32 бита и мы переходим к следующим `N` символам.

Декодеру, соответственно, нужно каким-либо образом сообщить N и размер одного слова - 32 бита. Очевидно также, что делать эти самые слова, например, 64 битными, достаточно бессмысленно, если при операциях `FPU` используется тип длиной 32 бита *(просто зря потратим место).*

---

*Рекомендую к прочтению также раздел статьи с **[Википедии,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding#Adaptive_arithmetic_coding)** поясняющий про точность и адаптивное арифметическое кодирование.*

Comment: Сжатия никакого не будет, т.к. в double у меня влазит кодировка до 10-13 символов. Т.е. в файл мне надо записать конечный предел и таблицу интервалов. А делать это для каждых 10 символов - бессмысленно, т.к. оно ничего не сожмет...